# Issue Uninstall Xcode 3.2.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, uninstall, sudo

Xcode 3.2.6 is here -> `/Applications/Developer/Applications/Xcode`

uninstall --> `$ sudo Applications/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all`

Problem--> `sudo: Applications/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found`

Why does it happen?

o_0

Comment: Missing a `/` before `Applications`?

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
sudo /Applications/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

you forgot the `/`